# python print square root iterations for a series using for in range

Tags: python, loops, sum, range

I'm working on a homework assignment on loops and iterations - squaring and summing numbers using 'for...in range()' and need some help.  Could someone show me how to fix this code? It should print the sum of a series of squares, for example, given `0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2` it should print `5`

```
import sys
N= int(sys.argv[1])

total = 0

for ctr in range (0, N+1):
  total = ctr**2
  total = (ctr + 1)**2

print(str(total))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works:

```
import sys
N= int(sys.argv[1])

total = 0

for ctr in range(0, N+1):
  total += ctr**2

print(total) #Note that I removed the usage of str().
             #print() works with any data type
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying.  This was simple and it worked when I ran it.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.